# Extract each day rows automatically based on start date & end date columns from API using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, api

I have to run python script daily to extract only latest records of particular day & that latest records should be appended to one csv file.

here am having 4 columns startdate, enddate, virtual_id, value

```
data = 'startdate': {0:'2022-12-19 06:01:12+00:00', 
                           1: '2022-12-19 13:49:09+00:00', 
                           2: '2022-12-19 13:20:36+00:00',
                           3: '2022-12-08 13:55:09+00:00', 
                           4: '2022-12-08 13:32:36+00:00', 
                           5: '2023-01-09 15:14:07+00:00', 
                           6: '2023-01-09 15:16:35+00:00'}, 
        'enddate': {0:'2022-12-19 06:25:06+00:00', 
                         1: '2022-12-19 13:59:29+00:00', 
                         2: '2022-12-19 13:26:40+00:00', 
                         3: '2022-12-08 13:55:27+00:00', 
                         4: '2022-12-08 13:45:41+00:00', 
                         5: '2023-12-09 15:29:39+00:00', 
                         6: '2023-01-09 15:28:43+00:00'}, 
        'virtual_id': {0: 1122, 1: 1125, 2: 1144,3: 1100, 4: 1136, 5: 1181, 6:1188}, 
        'value': {0:2000, 1: 5000, 2: 70000, 3: 8000, 4: 90000,5: 7200, 6: 81000}
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Expected output for the 09th Jan
if i run script on 09th Jan expected output should show records for the 8th Jan not previous day 07,06 etc to that similarly

```
data = 'startdate': {0: '2022-12-08 13:55:09+00:00', 
                     1: '2022-12-08 13:32:36+00:00',}, 
        'enddate': { 0: '2022-12-08 13:55:27+00:00', 
                     1: '2022-12-08 13:45:41+00:00', }, 
        'virtual_id': {0:1144, 1:1100}, 
        'value': {0: 70000, 1: 8000}
        }
```

if i run script on 10th Jan expected output should show records for the 9th Jan itself not 08th, 07th, 06th etc

```
data = 'startdate': {0: '2023-01-09 15:14:07+00:00', 
                     1: '2023-01-09 15:16:35+00:00'}, 
        'enddate': { 0: '2023-12-09 15:29:39+00:00', 
                     1: '2023-01-09 15:28:43+00:00' }, 
        'virtual_id': {0:1181, 1:1188}, 
        'value': {0: 7200, 1: 81000}
        }
```

i have tried below snippets but not working

```
data = data[data.startdate == data.startdate.max()] & data[data.enddate == data.enddate.max()]

data = data.loc[[data.enddate.idxmax()]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a costume function.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

def extract_latest_records(df):
    df['startdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startdate'])
    df['date'] = df['startdate'].dt.date
    current_date = datetime.now().date()
    df = df[df['date'] == current_date] 
    df = df.drop('date', axis=1)
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    return df
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

latest_df = extract_latest_records(df)
print(latest_df)
```

Output:

```
                  startdate                    enddate  virtual_id  value
0 2023-01-09 15:14:07+00:00  2023-12-09 15:29:39+00:00        1122   8000
1 2023-01-09 15:16:35+00:00  2023-01-09 15:28:43+00:00        1188  90000
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing output if i run today twice [morning & evening] it should show only evening latest records not morning records. can i do something for that

Comment: I think this should solve your problem now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works for you or not, but one issue you may be having is that your `startdate` and `enddate` columns are currently strings instead of datetime objects. Converting them to `datetime` allows you to access different parts, such as the date, day, hour, minute etc.

The second thing is that I think you want to keep rows that are EITHER max start or max end date so that you end up with the last two rows as in your example. This means you need a `|` instead of an `&`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['startdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startdate']) #convert from str to datetime
df['enddate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['enddate']) #convert from str to datetime

#filter to rows w/ either the max start or end date
out_df = df[
    df.startdate.dt.date.eq(df.startdate.dt.date.max())
    | df.enddate.dt.date.eq(df.enddate.dt.date.max())
]

print(out_df)
```

Output:

```
                  startdate                   enddate  virtual_id  value
3 2023-01-09 15:14:07+00:00 2023-12-09 15:29:39+00:00        1122   8000
4 2023-01-09 15:16:35+00:00 2023-01-09 15:28:43+00:00        1188  90000
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing output can I do difference of lastrun time and endtime by creating lastruntime column?

Comment: can you edit your question to show what you want that to look like?